# convert python to jupyter containing a single cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I having an environment in which ipynb files are executed, but I would like to write in py. I have been trying p2j, but, it converts a single py script to a large number of cells. Is there a simple way (other than writing it myself) to convert py to ipynb in a single cell - rather than splitting the py to different cells at each comment and line? I am using Ubuntu WLS.

Comment: Typically, you go the other way with `nbconvert`, or you can simply import modules into notebooks for use. What use-case do you have for this?

Comment: @OneCricketeer you could say the use-case is me. I am personally not wanting to use Jupyter Notebooks - but need to supply one for the rest of the existing process to work. When it is uploaded, it is easier for me to manipulate it if it has only one cell. So, the use case is - someone who wants to write in Python using Jupyter.

Comment: But, as mentioned, that one cell could also be `import app; app.main()`, for example, with `app.py` sitting somewhere in the pythonpath of the notebook

Comment: @OneCricketeer Entirely understood. But, what I wanted was to write Python in vi, and then have a bash script that converted that to a notebook for upload to JupyterHub. Using your approach is not in the spirit of my question which was - convert py to ipynb in one cell.

Comment: Sure, but let's say that Python code changes, then you need to re-run this conversion. Compared, to what I suggested, you simply need to create a single cell with the import/function call, then you can update the Python script however you want in the background, then re-running the same cell will call the new code.

Comment: @OneCricketeer True enough - if you are uploading the same python file all the time. But, in my context, I will want to write multiple different python files with different temporary names and functions. So for each of these I would need to generate one of the loader notebooks. And for me - the conversion is simply put in the bash script that prepares the python file, so it is do-once-and-never-again. I just automatically get an ipynb file that I can put onto the Jupyter server when I need to use it there.

Comment: @OneCricketeer perhaps it was not made clear -- in my context Python is the main game. I am writing Python all the time. Not Jupyter Notebooks. Python is the driver, So, this one context where I have to construct an ipynb file can be more easily handled by adding a conversion step into the make and bash when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Jupyter Notebook](https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format_description.html) is just a JSON file. So you can read your source file into a list of lines, then put that list into the `ipynb` structure. After that, dump the content into a file.

```py
import json

SOURCE = "source.py"
OUTPUT = "output.ipynb"

jupyter_file_content = {
    "cells": [
        {
            "cell_type": "code",
            "metadata": {},
            "source": list(open(SOURCE, encoding="utf-8"))
        },
    ],
    "metadata": {},
    "nbformat": 4,
    "nbformat_minor": 2
}

with open(OUTPUT, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json.dump(jupyter_file_content, file)
```

But it's a lot easier to just copy and paste the code into a cell though.

Comment: Thanks. The key piece of information that I should have already realized is that lis(open(..)) has the effect of doing all the right escaping. It was that bit that I was hoping to avoid. I modified your code and put it in a bash script. Does exactly what I want.